# Is it possible to run multi-threaded communication ActiveX code inside IE11?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, internet-explorer, activex

I have Delphi XE5 executable with GUI, which runs few threads, talking to server. I converted it into ActiveX component inside IE11. GUI works, but threads seem to be not executing, or running in the same thread as GUI. Should I change anything in this Delphi code, or it's impossible to run multi-threaded ActiveX code inside IE11?

```
procedure TMeetingForm.ActiveFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin// child form that is a normal Delphi TForm. Can be used as a normal VCL form and as an ActiveForm.
 GUI := TGUI.Create( TComponent(Sender) );
 GUI.Parent := Self;
 GUI.Align := alClient;
 GUI.BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;

initialization
  TActiveFormFactory.Create(
    ComServer,
    TActiveFormControl,
    TMeetingForm,
    Class_MeetingForm,
    0,
    '',
    OLEMISC_SIMPLEFRAME or OLEMISC_ACTSLIKELABEL,
    tmApartment);
end.
```

Comment: The most likely issue is the use of thread synchronization methods within your threads that are dependent on the main VCL thread.  If you build code into a COM object you need to take care that you don't rely on any such methods (eg TThread.Synchronize, TThread.Queue etc.).  Beyond that it is definitely possible to have threads operating in a COM object.  A good test for this situation can be to run your ActiveX imported into Delphi as the presence of a VCL main thread may then cause it to work.